# Using variables in Python to communicate with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I've been trying to place variables inside my SQL command. However, when I try this:

```
def interact_database(command):
    connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=NAME user=NAME password=PASSWORD")
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(command)
    connection.commit()

    results = None
    try:
        results = cursor.fetchall()
    except psycopg2.ProgrammingError:
        print("Connection failure.")
        pass

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    return results


def pick_question(type):
    if type == 'G':
        QuestionID = random.randint(1,38)
    elif type == 'Gr':
        QuestionID = random.randint(39,60)
    elif type == 'R':
        QuestionID = random.randint(61,89)
    else:
        QuestionID = random.randint(90,119)
    interact_database("SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE Question_ID = %s")(QuestionID)

pick_question('G')
```

I get this error

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE Question_ID = %s
```

I've tried Googling it multiple times, but everywhere I read this should work. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common newby mistake to attempt to wrap a database connectivity api in one's own class. It *always* leads to problems like this. So don't

```
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=NAME user=NAME password=PASSWORD")
cursor = connection.cursor()

def pick_question(type, cursor):
    if type == 'G':
        QuestionID = random.randint(1,38)
    elif type == 'Gr':
        QuestionID = random.randint(39,60)
    elif type == 'R':
        QuestionID = random.randint(61,89)
    else:
        QuestionID = random.randint(90,119)

    cursor.execute("SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE Question_ID = %s" , (QuestionID,))
    connection.commit()


pick_question('G', cursor)
```

Comment: What should I put in after  'G' in pick_question('G')? I get the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'cursor'"

Comment: Ooh I see what's wrong now. In my database I'm searching for an integer 1, but the code searches for the string '1' with %s, right? That's why I get no results when I run the code, because they're two different things. However, when I try to replace %s with %i or %d I get the error "ValueError: unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index %Id". I think I can fix this by editting the database, but can I also fix it by editting my Python code somehow?

Comment: I've editted my previous post, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: "but the code searches for the string '1' with %s, right?" nopes, postgresql will do automatic type conversion here and reconize that 1 = '1' so %s is indeed teh correct placeholder to use here

Comment: This answer does solve the problem that you posted, pertaining t the query not being executed. Your not getting any results is a different matter worthy of another question. However I suspect that the table doesn't contain the data that you expect it has

Comment: I've tested it with another database in which Question_ID is a varchar and it doesn't work there either, I get an error message. I think you're right about my database, so I'll take a look on how to fix that instead. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @e4c5 why isn't a good choice to have a connection function? I regularly find this python approach in a lot of code...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed your variable to the SQL query. All you've done is place it *next* to the call to your `interact_database` function. You need to modify that function to accept the data, and then to pass that to `cursor.execute`; and then actually pass the data to the function. So:

```
def interact_database(command, params=None):
    ...
    cursor.execute(command, params)

...
interact_database("SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE Question_ID = %s", (QuestionID,))
```

Comment: I editted my code to what you suggested, however I still get no output when I either print(pick_question('G')) or when I just call it. I don't get an error message anymore however.